# Populate and Update JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, populate

I have a little problem, i'm trying to show data on two JList, but the data that i want to show is located in a diferent class

Inside of the class with the data, i have a singleton declared to use the class in every additional class on the program, the code that i have in the class is the next:

```
HashMap<String, String[]> lista = new HashMap<>();
DefaultListModel listaArticulosAgregados;

private static inventario instance;

public static inventario getInstance()
{

    if(instance==null)
    {
        instance=new inventario();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I declare DefaultListModel here, inside of this class, and then i initialize the object inside of the class where the JList is located, but that is not working for me, no information is showed in the JList, the code that i have to initialize the JList is the next:
    in.listaArticulosAgregados = new DefaultListModel();
    listaElementos = new javax.swing.JList(in.listaArticulosAgregados);

And i don´t know if i need to perform something else before showing the information in the JList.

Additional, to update the contents of the datalist i have the next code:

```
listaArticulosAgregados.addElement(Id);
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Your question is not clear, start by putting the entire class code.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I'd also do more research into the singleton pattern and how to implement it, as it stands, it's possible to have more then once instance of your class created